# ApacheDS gidNumber not declared in objectClasses

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I follow the tutorial on how to create groups and users in LDAP Apache Directory Studio.

I use the posixGroup to create a group
to create users inetOrgPerson, posixAccound, shadowAccount

However, entries do not contain gidNumber and uidNumber and can not be added.

How do I add gidNumber for groups and uid Number for users?

I do not get gidNumber when I create it if I try to add it manually:

> Error while creating entry
>    - [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUES   java.lang.Exception: [LDAP: error code 65 -
>   OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message
>   ID : 13
>       Add Request : Entry
>       dn: cn=Vydaj,ou=Testgroups,dc=test,dc=com
>       objectClass: posixGroup
>       objectClass: top
>       gidNumber: 1000
>       cn: Vydaj : ERR_277 Attribute gidNumber not declared in objectClasses of entry cn=Vydaj,ou=Testgroups,test,dc=com]
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1418)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$11(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1386)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$6.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1312)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1256)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.createEntry(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.createEntry(CreateEntryRunnable.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.run(CreateEntryRunnable.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>
> [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for
>   MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 13
>       Add Request : Entry
>       dn: cn=Vydaj,ou=Testgroups,dc=test,dc=com
>       objectClass: posixGroup
>       objectClass: top
>       gidNumber: 1000
>       cn: Vydaj : ERR_277 Attribute gidNumber not declared in objectClasses of entry cn=Vydaj,ou=Testgroups,dc=test,dc=com]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the values within the Apache Directory Studio "Create an Object" wizard -- when you create an object with objectClass posixGroup, you should have an "Integer Editor" where you type the group gidNumber. When you create a user with posixAccount as an objectClass, you'll get a dialog box that has several attributes highlighted in red. Double-clicking the red text, or the empty cell in the "Value" column next to the red text, will allow you to edit that attribute value.

You could always create a general user or group *first* and then add the appropriate POSIX objectClass and required attributes. Since the objectClass has mandatory attributes, this needs to be performed as a single operation. An example LDIF that takes an inetOrgPerson user account, adds posixAccount as an objectClass, and adds the POSIX attributes (which are mandatory v/s optional depend on your schema definition):

```
dn: cn=something,ou=someou,o=company
changetype: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: posixAccount
-
add: uidNumber
uidNumber: 55555
-
add: gidNumber
gidNumber: 555
-
add: homeDirectory
homeDirectory: /home/userid
-
add: loginShell
loginShell: /bin/bash
-
add: gecos
gecos: UserDisplay Name
-
add: description
description: UserDisplay Name
-
```